# SIOCGIFADDR: Cannot assign requested address Error in python

Tags: python, linux, network-programming

I want to set IP address by using python's subprocess module.

I was trying to use it like this:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["ifconfig", "eth0", "192.168.1.5", "netmask", "255.255.255.0", "broadcast", "192.168.2.255"])
```

When I run this script in my CentOS server I get this error:

```
SIOCGIFADDR: Cannot assign requested address
SIOCSIFBROADCAST: Cannot assign requested address
SIOCSIFBRDADDR: Cannot assign requested address
```

I couldn't figure out where this error came from.

Comment: Your IP address and broadcast address are in different subnets.  This cannot possibly work. Either your broadcast address or IP address is wrong, OR the netmask must be 255.255.252.0

Comment: BTW, this has nothing to do with Python so it is probably off-topic for SO; probably belongs on [su].